# Android Development: Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an app for Android. When I try to run it, I get this in the console:

```
[2012-05-16 11:49:52 - LDAPLookUp] 
        Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

[2012-05-16 11:49:52 - LDAPLookUp] Please check logcat output for more details.

[2012-05-16 11:49:52 - LDAPLookUp] Launch canceled!
```

And, in LogCat, there is this:

```
05-16 11:49:51.169: E/PackageManager(91): 
    Package com.ericbrian.ldaplookup requires unavailable shared library 
    com.unboundid.android.ldap.*; failing!

05-16 11:49:51.169: W/PackageManager(91): 
    Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.ericbrian.ldaplookup-2.apk
```

In the Referenced Libraries, I have `unboundid-ldapsdk-se.jar`.

In the manifest, I have:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@drawable/logo" >
    <uses-library
        android:name="com.unboundid.android.ldap.*" />

... snip ...
</application>
```

What am I missing to get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I missing to get this to work?

You need to delete the `<uses-library>` element. That is not used for third-party JARs.

You also need to ensure that your third-party JAR is in in your project's `libs/` directory, creating that directory if needed. That will automatically add the JAR to your build path, and so you can get rid of whatever you did to manually add it to "Referenced Libraries".

Comment: I am getting the same error with com.google.android.gms.auth ... i dont have uses-library and the jars are in my libs/ .. still its not working